# Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error build callback listeners; entity was already processed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence

Error creating bean with entitymanagerfactory with the below cause 
when initialize the ehcacheregion factory.

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error build callback listeners; entity was already processed
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.addEntityCallbacks(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.LegacyCallbackProcessor.processCallbacksForEntity(LegacyCallbackProcessor.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator.integrate(JpaIntegrator.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 29 more
```

hibernate version is 4.3.6, hibernate jpa 2.1, hibernate-ehcache-4.3.6, 
secondarylevel cache is true.

I have entity declared int eh mapping file in a single time and it has the sub-class when its defined for three times with descrimnation value different. Its a upgrade activity

Comment: Can anybody please help me i am not able to clear this

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with Hibernate 4.3.x: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8775

Maybe try with the latest 4.2.x version to see if that helps?